# How can I export the Broken Links report from Sitecore out ? I am on Sitecore version 7.0

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, broken-links

I can generate the reports in Sitecore, but the results come back is very big report.
How can I export them out into XCEL to email them or filter them ?

Comment: Please provide some more information

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code you can use to get broken links. You can use it to generate Excel sheet or whatever you want:

```cs
Globals.LinkDatabase.Rebuild(database);
ItemLink[] brokenLinks = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetBrokenLinks(database);
foreach (ItemLink itemLink in brokenLinks)
{
    Item sourceItem = itemLink.GetSourceItem();
    if (sourceItem != null)
    {
    CustomField field = FieldTypeManager.GetField(sourceItem.Fields[itemLink.SourceFieldID]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you install the Advanced System Reporter module available on the Marketplace - https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Advanced_System_Reporter.aspx.

This module comes with a few reports and one of them is a "broken links" report.

Comment: I think I already have this report.  When I log in to Sitecore, I click on Control Panel and see a panel, one of the tab is Reports , and click on the option "Scan the database for broken links".   I select "master" database and click on "Scan", and the report got generated online for me, I can scroll through the reports, but I wish I could export it out into an XCEL.

Comment: What you are describing is the out-of-the-box reporting feature that comes with Sitecore.  I suggested you install a specific module that will enhance the Sitecore reporting features significantly - https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Advanced_System_Reporter.aspx.